# How to refere to a different schema in @DatabaseTable

Tags: mysql, ormlite

I'm using Ormlite on top of a MySQL-database. In MySQL there is possible to refere to a none default schemas like this:

```
SELECT * FROM schema_name.table_name;
```

Full of hope I tried to do the same on the DatabaseTable annotation like this:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "schema_name.table_name")
public class PojoObject {
   ...
```

It didn't work.

The reson why I can't just use a different `ConnectionSource` when creating a DAO is because attributes of the PojoObject are not stored in the same schema.

Is there some way to include the schema in the DatabaseTable annotation or is there some other way to solve the problem?

Comment: In what way did it fail? Was there an error?

Comment: When creating a table it creates the table `schema_name.table_name` in the default schema instead of the table `table_name` in the schema `schema_name`. Maybe Ormlite just puts some ' around the entire tableName-string and that confuses the DBMS?

Comment: Almost certainly it does add some ` (it is the only way I can think to name a table with a full stop). Sorry, cannot immediately think of a way round this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's looks like Ormlite just add ` on the begining and the end of the tableName-string.

To work around it just add two ` on each side of the . like this:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "schema_name`.`table_name")
```